# How to update an Entry Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net-2010

I can add delete update search and edit my simple pos system . 
But I have a little bit of a problem .

My professor requested this to add on my systemExample On my database I have an itemname called NUTELLA and its quantity is 10If I put Nutella/NUTELLA and Quantity is 30 on my inventory system it should not create a new line on my database and the quantity should add so it suppose to be ItemName : NUTELLA Quantity: 40

I hope you help me with my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

qry = "update tablename set Quantity=Quantity + '" & Quantity.text & "' 
where lower(ItemName) = '" & LCase(ItemName.text) & "'"